# How to access cookie from different controller (site-wide) in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I am trying to get cookie value from different controllers and views but in vain.

Here I am using it to save the cookie :

```
HttpCookie cookie =new HttpCookie("CLOCK");
cookie.Values["V"]="Some value";
cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30);
cookie.Path = "/";
cookie.HttpOnly = true;
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

It is working fine but when I try to retrieve that back it is showing null here I am using :

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["CLOCK"];
```

Here **"cookie"** always returns **null** when I am using from a different view and controller.

I want to access this cookie site-wide (from anywhere on the website).

Please help and I am stuck. Thank you.

**EDIT :**
I can access the cookie now but if I pass the cookie value to another method outside of the controller to authenticate the cookie it can not get detected and returns **NULL**.
Here I am using :

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["CLOCK"];
string id=AppCookie.GetId(cookie.value);
```

In **AppCookie** class **GetId** is a method to return the **id** from the cookie. But it is not working, it always returning **NULL**.

Please help.

Comment: Try with: Request.Cookies.Get("CLOCK');

Comment: @pcalkins I am using Request.Cookie.Get("CLOCK") to retrieve data but it can not be passed to another method to validate or authenticate. Can you help me?